# Android studio can't resolve org.junit import

Tags: android-studio, junit, gradle

I'm growing pretty desperate. 
I follow JetBrain guide to install and use Junit in an Android app of mine.

So dependency is imported in gradle app file:

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7+'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.+'
testCompile 'org.robolectric:robolectric:2.4'
testCompile 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.+'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'}
```

I've switched also build variants on unit tests.

But android studio can't resolve typical annotation symbols of Junit for neither import any packages from "org.junit". 
I've try to find something here and on google, try to invalidate cache and restart. I've try to use junitgenerator plugin, and write test in src/test/java/ my self...

To me seems that gradle does not import the junit jar at all. Any ideas how to solve this issue? Probably an AS issue?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Android Studio do you have?

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: Hello, I am getting same problem please help me.